# In gnuradio，if there an't any connection between the size of the input data and the size of the output data ,how should I set the noutput_items?

Tags: gnuradio

I had set up a OOT block in gnuradio,it has one input and one output,the size of the input data is 100 and the size of output data is 32000,I had succeed in compling and installing the block,but when I tried to use th block in gnuradio,it crashed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJzeu.png)

When I set the size of the output data to noutput_items,it could work,but the size of the output data was not I want.

I am a new player of the gnuradio,so I need some help, thanks a lot.

```
void
testInAndOut_impl::forecast (int noutput_items, gr_vector_int &ninput_items_required)
{
  /* <+forecast+> e.g. ninput_items_required[0] = noutput_items */
  ninput_items_required[0] = noutput_items; 
}

int
testInAndOut_impl::general_work (int noutput_items,
                   gr_vector_int &ninput_items,
                   gr_vector_const_void_star &input_items,
                   gr_vector_void_star &output_items)
{
  const float *in0 = (const float *) input_items[0];
  // const float *in1 = (const float *) input_items[1];
  float *out = (float *) output_items[0];

  float *sig_data = new float[100];       

  // get the first 100 numbers for the input data
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)     
  {
    sig_data[i] = in0[i];
  }

  // 
  for (int i = 0; i < 320; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
    {
      out[j + i * j] = sig_data[j];   
    }
  }
  // Do <+signal processing+>
  // Tell runtime system how many input items we consumed on
  // each input stream.
  consume_each (noutput_items);
  
  delete[] sig_Data;

  // Tell runtime system how many output items we produced.
  return noutput_items;
}
```

Comment: Hi! This is impossible to answer without you adding the code of your block to your question (please, don't post pictures of text – copy&paste the text instead into your question, and use the "code formatting" button)!

Comment: My working code may be a bit long, so I feel it might not be appropriate to put all my code here. I wrote a demo and it has the same problem as my code. Hopefully I can get some instructions from you.

Comment: this program is leaking a lot of memory and will crash by itself! you really must not use `new` here.

Comment: also, you're not checking whether there's actually 100 input items or space for 32000 output items, so none of this works that way.

Comment: The input data is from  a source module which I had created, the source module should generate 100 valid data and transfer to the test module.In the test module,the size of input data is always larger that 100,so I think it's neccessary to create an array and put the 100 valid data in it.

Comment: How should I check whether there's space for 32000 output items? Or how can I output 32000 items?

Comment: if you can,can you write a demo for my problems?

Comment: We would have to set up a consulting contract for that; I'm currently only doing contracts of more than 20 hrs, and take an industry-standard hourly rate.